# Arguments for a Socratic Daimon and Embodiment: A Dialogue between an A-pneumatic and Pneumatic: Is this coherent?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, mind-body, ancient-philosophy

**Dear all, can you help me find any inconsistencies from theory of mind, philosophy of mind and phenomenology of percetion in this dialogue?**

A conversation between an a-pneumatic and a pneumatic:

**A-pneumatic:** You clearly believe you have a daimon that rules over you?

**Pneumatic:** This daimon is my Self, and I am the ruler of myself

**A-pneumatic:** You clearly are aware that the mental processes, identity, memories are a paradox that create the selfhood?

**Pneumatic:** That is so, but the selfhood is the the complex that the Daimon rules.

**A-pneumatic:** Can a Daimon exist separately from a selfhood?

**Pneumatic:** They may coexist, but when the ruler is gone, the cadaver remains, and the Daimon leaves the tomb.

**A-Pneumatic:** You posit a separable entity with an ontological objective status, can you prove it without self-referential attributions to the selfhood?

**Pneumatic:** By experience, I may prove it subjectively and inter-subjectively, but by reason, I will try: Imagine that a man has the idea of freedom, yet he is enslaved, to liberate himself apart from the need to return to a pleasant state, what drives him onwards?

**A-Pneumatic:** Perhaps the memory of him being free, but that doesn’t solve the question.

**Pneumatic:** When a man is of strong ethos and nature and will, but somehow his will, ethos and nature are broken and he discerns is, what is it?

**A-Pneumatic:** He finds a contradiction between these states, that would posit a Third psychic complex, but that is fully understood in psychology.

**Pneumatic:** There are old Delphic adages “Know thyself” and “E” discover the Gods and Goddesses within, if one knows oneself and discerns what is that third that you talk about?

**A-Pneumatic:** Consciousness of difference, perhaps

**Pneumatic:** Can a mind procure a difference outside of itself and resolve it in meta-rhetorical fashion, given that limits of the mind are the limits of the selfhood?

**A-Pneumatic:** Well, in theory it may.

**Pneumatic:** What happens when you deprive the man of that discernment and difference?

**A-Pneumatic:** He becomes a machine, an automaton

**Pneumatic:** Therefore there is an embodied daimon, even if you psychologize it, there the mystery of the “daimon ruling over us” in contained, even if you don’t metaphysize, the daimon is and must be, therefore it may be trained, perfected, and eventually liberated like a pearl, after the cadaver is shed.

Thank you

Comment: How to further explain the procurement of a difference outside of an embodied daimon? Once you claim the existence of a 'difference outside of itself' a contradiction or paradox of head upon head may arise...